# can I use tkinter with blender?

Tags: python, game-engine, development

I want make game engine

i can use  bpy without run blender but I do not know how to create gui with bpy

is there are way to create gui with bpy or use by with tkinter

Comment: Possibly related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143687/pyqt-and-tkinter-seem-to-not-work-with-blender-2-8  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55332/bge-import-error-no-module-named-tkinter